# Volume control reset on cast playback?

Tags: android, chromecast, volume

I'm working on an audio app that currently uses Cast SDK v2 with a RemoteMediaPlayer to play on a ChromeCast device.

I'm setting the volume controls by `setVolumeControl(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC)` which works until I start playback for ChromeCast.

Out of strange reasons while playback on the ChromeCast goes on the volume control is always triggered for notifications (I think it resets the volume control somewhere to `USE_DEFAULT_STREAM_TYPE`) but as soon as I pause playback it works fine again.

I've searched the whole project for `setVolumeControl` or the like but couldn't find anything that leads to a reason why this happens.

Hopefully you guys can help me out.

Comment: As what was stated in your question, I think [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53500578/volume-button-not-controlling-casting-device-volume-from-android-sender-app-usin) has the same issue with you. It could be a possible issue in your device and your OS in which advised to report it [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:190205%20status:open&s=modified_time:desc) for further support.

Comment: Could using the application context instead of the activity context lead to such a bug?